# How to dynamically generate key and assign values to a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic

I have a list of dictionaries as input :

```
[{
Acc: "ABC IN."
CFC: "XC"
CC: "1001"
SC: "DER"
Config Path: "..//"
File Path: "..//"
}]
```

I wanted to convert it into a template nested dictionary the only catch being the key of the nested dictionary is also derived from the above dictionary itself
Desired output

```
{'XC': {'1001': {'DER': {'Config Path': '..//' ,'File Path' : "..//" }}}}
```

The input can be multiple and whenever a new CFC , CC or SC arrives a new key is generated on the same level as that of the previous .

I tried dynamically generating key but it was showing key not found error

```
main_dict = {}
for item in main_dict_list:
    main_dict[item['CFC']][item['CC']][item['SC']]['Config Path']=item['Config Path']
    main_dict[item['CFC']][item['CC']][item['SC']]['File Path']=item['File Path']
```

I also tried to follow hierarchy to input key-value from inside the dictionary

```
main_dict = {}


for item in main_dict_list:
 
    temp={}
    temp['model_config_path']=item['Config Path']
    temp['model_config_path']=item['File Path']
    temp1 = {}
    temp1[item['SC']] = temp
    temp2 ={}
    temp2[item['CC']] =temp1
    main_dict[item['CFC']] =temp2
```

it also doesn't seem to work properly.
I am not able to think about any other solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to create each level.

```
main_dict = {}
for item in main_dict_list:
    main_dict[item['CFC']] = {item['CC']: {item['SC']: {'Config Path': item['Config Path'], 'File Path': item['File Path']}}}
```

Comment: the above code seems to over write if any new entry / key is added to a level - not working as supposed to

Comment: You didn't specify that as a requirement.  Perhaps you need to expand your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setdefault to auto-merge common keys:

```
main_dict_list = [
     { 'Acc': "ABC IN.",
       'CFC': "XC",
       'CC': "1001",
       'SC': "DER",
       'Config Path': "..//",
       'File Path': "..//"
     },
     { 'Acc': "ABC IN.",
       'CFC': "XC",
       'CC': "1002",
       'SC': "DER",
       'Config Path': "..//c",
       'File Path': "..//f"
     },
]

main_dict = dict()

for d in main_dict_list:
    content = {k:d[k] for k in ("Config Path","File Path") }
    main_dict.setdefault(d["CFC"],dict()) \
             .setdefault(d["CC"],dict())  \
             .setdefault(d["SC"],content)

print(main_dict)
      
{'XC': {'1001': {'DER': {'Config Path': '..//', 'File Path': '..//'}},
        '1002': {'DER': {'Config Path': '..//c', 'File Path': '..//f'}}}}
```